# Is it possible to remove gdb aliases without restarting gdb?

Tags: gdb, alias

Suppose I define a [new gdb command](https://github.com/hq6/GdbAsciiHexPrint/blob/master/AsciiPrintCommand.py) which includes an alias.

```
import gdb
import string
class PrettyPrintString (gdb.Command):
    "Command to print strings with a mix of ascii and hex."

    def __init__(self):
        super (PrettyPrintString, self).__init__("ascii-print",
                gdb.COMMAND_DATA,
                gdb.COMPLETE_EXPRESSION, True)
gdb.execute("alias -a pp = ascii-print", True)
```

Now, I'd like to make a small change to the script and source it again in the same gdb session. Unfortunately, when I try to source again, I get the following error.

```
gdb.error: Alias already exists: pp
```

**How can I delete the original alias and source the updated script?**

Note that the [alias documentation](https://www-zeuthen.desy.de/unix/unixguide/infohtml/gdb/Aliases.html) does not appear to say anything about deleting aliases, and I tried `unalias` and `delete` but neither had the desired effect.

Comment: I begin to think that there is no mechanism to do this...Nor does there seem to be a way to list aliases.  Nor does the gdb documentation seem to have a definitive list of built-in aliases (such as `s`).  If I had to guess, gdb has internal aliases, the removal of which would horribly break it, and no way to distinguish between user-created and its own...

Comment: I found this for the nth time. very frustrating. I've a gdb front end which comes with aliases some of which I want to turn off or at least see what they're doing without having to go dumpster diving.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a keyword to a function instead of as an alias. For example I have

```
define w
   where
end
```

in my .gdbinit. And re-defining works, as opposed to re-aliasing.